# jQuery - Hover over element and animate element to that position

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, element

I want to make a menu that.. does this: http://jsfiddle.net/8U9fy/1/ ( didnt want to bother positioning them all that well... ) But... i would like to make it so that it isnt menu/link size dependent.. ( something like assigning the arrow to move according to specific elements class.. or something )

I was thinking something like.. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position But i dont know if .animate can be used with it..

So, to make it clear.. problem really isnt positioning the arrow according to specific element but rather.. doing so while animating the arrow movement..

Ideas?

Edit: I would like to achieve something similar like what ive done in that jsfiddle example.. buti would like to do it so that it doesnt matter what size the menu or the links are...

Currently the arrow position is controlled by left values from one position which means that if i wanted to.. lets say add padding between the links, i would have to adjust the .animate left values again and again..

Comment: Could you rephrase the problem? It's not clear.

Comment: Are you saying that as you move the mouse from one menu item to the next the animation is smooth, rather than starting to move when you hit the next element?

Comment: maybe the Edit makes it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  You'll need to tweak the location calculation to your needs.

```
var arrow = $(".Arrow");
$("ul#menu").delegate('a', 'mouseenter', function() {
    var left = $(this).offset().left - arrow.parent().offset().left + $(this).outerWidth()/2 - arrow.width()/2
    arrow.stop().animate({left: left}, 800, 'easeOutBack');
});
```

(Edited to add kingjiv's 'left' calculation.)

Comment: @Talljoe That is quite nice.. but i was really hoping for solution that doesnt rely on any value changes

Comment: and.. that jquery ui position thingie seems to do that quite well and easy..except that as far a is know.. you cant .animate that... which i find kinda hard to believe..

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't rely on value changes"?  That example will work regardless of the size of the elements or the number of elements you have.  You just need to find the right calculation to put the arrow where you want relative to the position of the element.

Comment: @Talljoe well.. first of all.. there is that value change one has to do when first applying it to menu.. i know its not a big deal but in this case it matters.. PLus.. its quite dependent on having same sized elements.. http://jsfiddle.net/8U9fy/14/

Comment: @Talljoe http://jsfiddle.net/8U9fy/15/ as i said.. .position seems to do the job quite well.. i just dont know how i would .animate that...

Comment: @lollero can you explain further what is wrong with talljoe's solution?  aside from some slight tweaks to the calculation for left to center it better, it seems fine to me.  I'm not sure what you mean by "value changes".

Comment: @kingjiv Talljoe said it.. the location calculation needs to be tweaked to ones needs.. and that type of value changes are out of question and theres that issue of having different size buttons.. as this: http://jsfiddle.net/8U9fy/14/ shows..

Comment: @lollero I think you misunderstood.  The tweaking just needed to be done once depending on where you wanted the arrow located (centered, etc.)  See this http://jsfiddle.net/8U9fy/16/ , it is the tweaked version of @talljoe 's code.  It is independent of element size and centers the arrow.

Comment: @lollero, if you don't want to hard-code the menu selector then you can turn this code into a plugin (exercise left for the reader, but it's very simple).  It's impossible to write jQuery code that reads your mind and put the arrow exactly where you want it on only the elements you want, at some point you will need to tell it. :)

Comment: @kingjiv any value changing is a no go but The way you changed the code seems to do exactly how i want.. thought.. why are the values "2" ? i mean.. it seems to fit all sizes but i cant comprehend why.. Thanks.

@Talljoe i dont quite understand your arguement considering that .position that jquery ui has And whatkingjiv did with the code.. that could even be done with just html and css.. As far as the positioning goes... and i dont mind telling it where to go... just that i dont have to tell it over and over again if width values change... thank you for your efforts with the code as well

Comment: oh.. actually noticed that some editing was still required... but i suppose it is close enough... or i could always get rid of the animation... Thanks anyways

Comment: the 2's are to half the distance, the one adjusts it by half the width of the link the other adjusts it the other direction by half the width of the arrow, this is just to center it exactly.